# How to Pass value from @Url.Action to contoller in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I trying to pass value from @Url.Action to a controller but it is taking as Contoller/action/id and returns "no view found". Below is my code

**VIEW**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "DirectPutawayDetails", new { id = @home[j].test.ToString()})" class="ui-li-has-count" data-role="button"  data-ajax="false" data-mini="true" style="background-color:#52616D;color:white">
                @home[j].test.ToString() <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="background-color: white; color: #52616D">@home[j].think.ToString() </span></a>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {  
        directsearch.home.test = id;

        return view()    
    }
```

I am unable to assign my id value to home.test model property. It displays

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What does your directseach.home object contains? Could you please add additinal code for the view and the controller?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni I need to get value when user clicked a href tag and assign it to my model property test.

Comment: are you sure that *@home[j]* is not null ?

Comment: @ya. Acutally its in view model. actually using view model i placed 3 class in one view model. but unable to assign the value to class.

Comment: What is `@home[j]`? Are you constructing `@Url.Action(...` in a loop?

Comment: it means ``@home[j]`` or ``@home[j].test`` is null